# How to get ultimate or penultimate string regex

Tags: regex, regex-group

I've got a list of strings and I would like to group using a regular expression every _ character if present

```
Test1_MYSTRING_val1
Test1_MYSTRING
```

I would like to obtain:

```
Test1, MYSTRING, val1
Test1, MYSTRING
```

[This regex](https://regex101.com/r/iPGvTr/3) works for the first string but not for the second one: `(Test[\d])_([\w]+?)_([\w]+)`

Any suggest?

Comment: You're looking for a find and replacement, rather than a pure regex.

Comment: no I need a regex: comma in second box are only as example...

Comment: Would it not fit for you to split the strings on `_`?

Comment: If your regex is always in the format you are mentioning (words divided by `_`), then how about using a very simple one: [A-Za-z0-9]+ [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/oegIYe/1/)

Comment: @degant: Strings are longer than the example and I have to fit some rules, so I can't use your suggestion, moreover I have to group the results using the parenthesis group method of regex. The issue is that some strings ends with MYSTRING and others has another field separated with a character.

Comment: Okay, then how about [this](https://regex101.com/r/iPGvTr/4): `(Test\d)_([A-Za-z0-9]+)(?:_([A-Za-z0-9]+))?`

Comment: Exactly @degant. You can publish the solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, using split is a better approach. However, if you still need to use Regex, you can do it this way:

```
(Test\d)_([A-Za-z0-9]+)(?:_([A-Za-z0-9]+))?
```

- This will extract two or three capturing groups that are seperated by `_`
- The first one is of the format: `(Test\d)`
- The second one is of the format: `([A-Za-z0-9]+)` and will have *at least* one character
- The third one is of the same format `([A-Za-z0-9]+)` and `(?:_` ensures the underscore isn't captured and the whole thing is surrounded and marked with `?` to indicate that it (the third group) may or may not be present

Note: I changed `\w` to `[A-Za-z0-9]` instead because remember `\w` matches underscores `_` too

[Regex 101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iPGvTr/4)